# NodeJS module.exports, preserve array content

Tags: arrays, node.js

I just need to know how to preserve array content.
I make this but the array is empty when new users connect.

```
module.exports = function(){
    var clients = [];
    function push_clients(a) {
            clients.push(a);
    }
    global.socket.of('/fsdd6SDF86QS').on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('user-ready', function(data) {
                    console.log('init clients: '+clients);
                    push_clients(socket.id);
                    console.log('final clients: '+clients);
        });
    }
}();
```

Before I tried: `clients.push(socket.id);` but with same result.
Any idea ?

Comment: how are you using the exported function? i.e., can you show the code where you require this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case clients variable is local and there is no way to get it outside.
Better decision is to export just a function and then make an instance + making clients variable an object property:

```
module.exports = function(){
    this.clients= [];
    this.push_clients = function (a) {
            this.clients.push(a);
    }
    self = this;
    /* .. */
        console.log('init clients: '+clients);
        self.push_clients(socket.id); // or just self.clients.push(socket.id);
}
```

And in another module call it like:

```
var Sockets = require("your_module_path");
var sockets = new Sockets();
sockets.clients // here will collect connected users
```

Comment: Thank you for this reponse, but I'm starter in nodejs but I don't saw how add clients with external module.
If I do: sockets.push_clients(socket.id); does it wok ?

Comment: When you construct new instance ( var sockets = new Sockets(); ) your constructor function will be called and socket-server begins to listen the socket-client and on `user-ready` event will be called this.push_clients (sorry, I don't mentioned it) just be careful with `this` context